# Min and max for a multi variable function

Tags: analysis

We have $A=\left[-1,1\right]^2$

Find $minf\left(A\right)\:maxf\left(A\right)\:f\left(A\right)$ for function:
$$f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$f\left(x,y\right)\:=\:x^3+xy+y^3$$
So I'm guessing A is a compact set, since it's a closed interval and bounded(I think), and the function is continuous on A, thus $minf\left(A\right)\:maxf\left(A\right)$ should exist.

So I solve the system of equations: $$\frac{∂f}{∂x}=3x^2+y$$ $$\frac{∂f}{∂y\:}=x+3y^2$$ and I get:$x_1=0\:y_1=0\:and\:x_2=-\frac{1}{3}\:y_2=-\frac{1}{3}$

That would mean I have found the critical points of the function, the value of the function in these points being: $\:f\left(0,0\right)\:=\:0\:$ and $\:f\left(-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{3}\right)\:=\:\frac{1}{27}$

But how do I know which one is the max and which is the min? And how do I calculate $\:f\left(A\right)\:$ ?

Comment: I think you made a typo on your system of equations, should the first equation be with respect to $x$?

Comment: Those you found are the extremal points in the interior of your set... you still have to look for extremal points on the boundary!

Comment: @GrancescoFrechi Yes, I edited it now.

Comment: @b00nheT but how do I do that?

Comment: Restrict the function to the four lines $x=\pm1$ $y=\pm1$, and then you will find a function in just one variable. Set the derivative $=0$ to find the extremal points. If these lie in the range $(-1,1)$ keep them, else throw them away. Lastly, the four corners $(\pm1,\pm1)$ have to be considered as possible extremal points as well. Now write all the values of $f$ in these points, in a table, and compare the values. The lowest one will be the minimum, the biggest one the maximum.
PS: note that the function is indeed quite symmetric, so you need to do the above calculation only once, up to sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so to find extremum within the interior, you can set the gradient equal to $0$:

$$\nabla f(x,y)=\left(3x^2+y, 3y^2+x\right)=0$$

As you noted, the two solutions to this equation are $(0,0)$ and $\left(-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{3}\right)$.

Now, for the extremum on the boundary, we can split the boundary up into four different sections.

Right Edge:

On the right edge, $x=1$ while $-1\leq y\leq1$. So our function is now $y^3+y+1$. This is maximized when $y=1$ and minimized when $y=-1$.

Upper Edge:

Since $x$ and $y$ are symmetric, we conclude that the maximum and minimum on this edge occur at $x=1$ and $x=-1$ respectively.

Left Edge:

On the left edge, $x=-1$ while $-1\leq y\leq1$. So our function is now $y^3-y-1$. Setting the derivative to $0$, we get $3y^2-1=0$, so $y=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$. We also have to assess when $y=\pm 1$. After analyzing these points, we find that the maximum occurs at $y=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ while the minimum occurs at $y=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.

Bottom Edge:

Since $x$ and $y$ are symmetric, we conclude that the maximum and minimum on this edge occur at $x=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ and $x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ respectively.

Analyzing all these points, we get that the maximum occurs at $(1,1)$ where the value of the function is $3$, while the minima occur at $\left(-1,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},-1 \right)$, where the value of the function is $-1-\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{9}$.

Comment: Thank you! I have a small question thought, are $minf\left(A\right)$ and
$maxf\left(A\right)$ basically the extreme points of the function? And what about $f\left(A\right)$?

Comment: @MikhaelM I assumed that $minf(A)$ and $minf(A)$ were the maximum and minimum values of $f(x)$ over $A$. Unfortunately, I don't really know what $f(A)$ is.